# OnClick Event not detected on parentView in AChartEngine

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I use the following code to draw GraphView on LinearLayout,whose parent is a RelativeLayout

the code for drawing GraphView on LinearLayout

```
  mLinearView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearView);//ChildLayout
    mRelativeView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLay);//ParentLayout

YearXYGraph mYearGraph = new YearXYGraph();
                final GraphicalView mGraphView = mYearGraph.execution(
                        MainActivity.this, mGirlHeightYearFirstGrade,
                        mGirlHeightYearSecondGrade,
                        mGirlHeightYearThirdGrade,
                        mGirlHeightYearFourthGrade,
                        mGirlHeightYearFifthGrade, mGirlWeightYearFirstGrade,
                        mGirlWeightYearSecondGrade, mGirlWeightYearThirdGrade,
                        mGirlWeightYearFourthGrade, mGirlWeightYearFifthGrade);
                mLinearView.addView(mGraphView);
```

onclicking LinearLayout I'm Showing a popup,code follows

```
mGraphView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    double[] xy = mGraphView.toRealPoint(0);
                       p = new Point();
                          p.x = (int) xy[0];
                          p.y = (int) xy[1];

                          if (p != null){
                              showPopup(MainActivity.this, p);
                            }
                }
            });
```

Im also using onClick event on ParentLayout to get some coordinate

```
mRelativeView.setOnTouchListener(new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        System.out.println("in--");
                        p1 = new Point();
                        p1.x = (int) event.getX();
                        p1.y = (int) event.getY();
                        System.out.println("x--"+p1.x);
                            return false;
                    }
                });
```

code for Showing popup

```
// The method that displays the popup.
private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
   int popupWidth = 75;
   int popupHeight = 40;
   // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
   LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);

   // Creating the PopupWindow
   final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
   popup.setContentView(layout);
   popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
   popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
   popup.setFocusable(true);

    Rect location = new Rect();
    location.left =p1.x;
    location.top = p1.y;
    location.right = location.left + popup.getWidth();
    location.bottom = location.top + popup.getHeight();

 /*  // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
   int OFFSET_X = 30;
   int OFFSET_Y = 30;*/

   // Clear the default translucent background
   popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

   // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
  // popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, location.left , location.bottom );
   popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, location.left , location.bottom );

   // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
   TextView firstView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   firstView.setText(p.x + " , " +p.y);
    firstView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

problem is onClickEvent not detected on ParentLayout,,Child Layout detects OnClick,please provide some suggestions

Comment: whats problem change Toast to Dialog ?

Comment: now its possible to show popup but I want to receive touch on parent relative layout where GrapphView inside Linear layout is embedded@keshav

Comment: Then use onTouchEvent, see  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html